# UnicodePython 3: EncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 277: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

When I tried to make request with python requests library like below. I am getting the below exception

```
def get_request(url):
    return requests.get(url).json()
```

Exception

```
    palo:dataextractor minisha$ python escoskill.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "escoskill.py", line 62, in <module>
    print(response.json())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 277: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, the same piece of code works for some request and not for all. For the below url, it doesn't work.

```
https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/concept?uri=http://data.europa.eu/esco/isco/C2&language=en
```

Url that works

```
https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/taxonomy?uri=http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/isco&language=en
```

Comment: I have tried with the url that shows and I have not had problems. Are you sure that the code that generates the problem?

Comment: Try using `json` module and decode into `UTF8`: `json.loads(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf8'))` Otherwise, i can't reproduce your error in my mahcine

Comment: response = requests.get('https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/concept?uri=http://data.europa.eu/esco/isco/C2&language=en')

    print(response.json())

Comment: Just the above piece of code throw the above exception. So I concluded that the code is the issue

Comment: I am getting the very same error for json.loads. ... Didn't understand why it is not working on my machine

Comment: I am using Mac for development , IDE IntelliJ . Can I know which platform you are using

Comment: @Minisha can you  check your default encoding ?  check the output of: `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: @ChihebNexus utf-8

Comment: I have just tried your `json.loads...` with both urls and I do not get any error, all works fine :/

EDIT: And with response.json() works too

Comment: @DanielRodríguez what am I missing in my system? Any pointers?

Comment: response.json() is the one that is giving problem in my system

Comment: maybe it is your requests version? Try posting the full traceback, maybe it could help

Comment: Looks like problem is IntelliJ IDE. When I try with terminal it works

Comment: It's a Unicode **Encode** error. All of you seem to be thinking decode. It's likely being raised by `print`, which is unable to emit a special character.

Comment: @Thanatos What the way to fix it in the IDE?

Comment: It would help to know what OS you're on, and where the output of your program is going or normally goes. Your last reply sounds like you're using an IDE; does it have a pane at the bottom that normally display's the output from `print`? What IDE are you using? And if you `print(repr(os.environ.get('LANG')))`, what does that say?

Comment: @Thanatos For the above one. I am getting None.. I am using IntelliJ IDE

Comment: @Minisha What operating system? (Windows, OS X, Linux, etc.?)

Comment: @Thanatos Mac Sierra (OS X)

Answer (score 2):

The exception you're getting, `UnicodeEncodeError`, means we have some character that we cannot *encode* into bytes. In this case, we're trying to encode `\xe4`, or ä, which ASCII¹ does not have, hence, error.

In this line of code:

```
print(response.json())
```

The only thing that's going to be doing encoding is the `print()`. `print()`, to emit text into something, needs to encode it to bytes. Now, what it does by default depends on what `sys.stdout` is. Typically, `stdout` is your screen unless you've redirected output to a file. On Unix-like OSs (Linux, OS X), the encoding Python will use will be whatever `LANG` is set to; typically, this should be something like `en_US.utf8` (the first part, `en_US`, might differ if you're in a different country; the `utf8` bit is what is important here). If `LANG` isn't set (this is unusual, but can happen in some contexts, such as Docker containers) then it defaults to `C`, for which Python will use ASCII as an encoding.

(**Edit**) From the additional information in the comments (you're on OS X, you're using IntelliJ, and `LANG` is unset (`print(repr(os.environ['LANG'])))` printed `None`)), this is a tough one to give advice on. `LANG` being unset means Python will assume it can only output ASCII, and error out, as you've seen, on anything else. In order of preference, I would:

- Try to figure out why `LANG` is unset. This might be some configuration of the mini-terminal in the IDE, if that is what you have and are using. This may prove hard to find if you're unfamiliar with character encodings, and I might be off-base here, as I'm unfamiliar with IntelliJ.
- Since you seem to be running your program from a command line, you can see if setting `LANG` helps. Where currently you are doing,

  ```
  python escoskill.py
  ```

  You can set `LANG` for a single run with:

  ```
  LANG=en_US.utf8 python escoskill.py
  ```

  If that works, you can make it last for however long that session is by doing,

  ```
  export LANG=en_US.utf8
  # LANG will have that value for all future commands run from this terminal.
  python escoskill.py
  ```
- You can override what Python autodetects the encoding to be, or you can override its behavior when it hits a character it can't encode. For example,

  ```
  PYTHONIOENCODING=ascii:replace 'print("\xe4")'
  ```

  tells Python to use the output encoding of ASCII (which is what it was doing before anyways) but the `:replace` bit will make characters that it can't encode in ASCII, such as ä, be emitted as `?`s instead of erroring out. This might make some things harder to read, of course.

<sub>¹ASCII is a character encoding. A character encoding tells one how to translate bytes into characters. There's not just one, because… humans.</sub>

<sub>²or perhaps your OS, but `LANG` being unset on OS X just sounds very implausible</sub>